# Can I access different template class object via a same pointer?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to access the `data_` member of `NDArray` class via the `getData()` member function.

```cpp
typedef void * datahandle_t;

enum class typeFlag {
kFloat32 = 0,
kFloat64 = 1,
kUint8 = 2
};

class NDArray{

    private:
        typeFlag dtype_;
        size_t size_;
        datahandle_t data_;

    public:
        // constructor
        NDArray(); 
        NDArray(const size_t size, typeFlag dtype);
        
        // alloc TBlob object
        void alloc();

        const auto getData() const {if (data_) return data_->dptr_;}
        // ...
}

inline NDArray::NDArray(): dtype_(typeFlag::kFloat32), size_(size),  data_(nullptr) {}
inline NDArray::NDArray(const size_t size, typeFlag dtype):  dtype_(dtype), size_(size) {alloc();}

inline void NDArray::alloc(){
        switch(dtype_){
            case typeFlag::kFloat32:
                data_ = std::make_shared<TBlob<float> >(size_);
                break;
            case typeFlag::kFloat64:
                data_ = std::make_shared<TBlob<double> >(size_);
                break;
            // ...
        }

template<typename dtype>
class TBlob{
    friend class NDArray;

    public:
        TBlob();
        explicit TBlob(const size_t size);
        ~TBlob();

    private:
        size_t size_;
        void *dptr_;
};

template<typename dtype>
inline TBlob<dtype>::TBlob(const size_t size): size_(size), dptr_(new dtype[size]) {}
```

Test code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

NDArray n(18, typeFlag::kFloat32);
for(int i=0; i<18; i++)  std::cout << int(n.getData()[i]) << " ";
```

First I construct a NDArray object by calling the `alloc()` in constructor. It will assign different `TBlob` object to the `void * data_` member;

Then I hope I can access the `TBlob` object I've made, and I got error:

```cpp
testTBlob.cc:52:60: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
     for(int i=0; i<18; i++)  std::cout << int(n.getData()[i]) << " ";
                                                            ^
testTBlob.cc:52:60: error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type
```

It seems that I still got an `void *` object.

I want to make a generic class `NDArray`, and `TBlob` is a template class containing different type (float, int, etc.) according to the member `dtype_`. I want to access the TBlob object via the `data_` member, so I expect it to not be a void*, but the smart pointer to the TBlob object.

How can I access the specific object that already constructed in the memory (for example, a `TBlob<float>` object) ?

Comment: You have to `reinterpret_cast` your `void*` pointer to a specific pointer type. But in your code there are many weird lines. E.g. you assign `std::shared_ptr` to `void*`, this should not even compile. You try to use `opertator[]` on your data, even though your `TBlob` class does not have this operator overloaded. Your example contains a lot of irrelevant code like context, shape, etc. Post the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead.

Comment: Why would you expect it to not be a void*, by the way?

Comment: @pptaszni I have edited by now, and the ```operator[]``` is perform on built-in array.

Comment: @user253751 I want to make a generic class ```NDArray```, and ```TBlob``` is a template class containing different type (float, int, etc.) according to the member ```dtype_```. I want to access the ```TBlob``` object via the ```data_``` member, so I expect it to not be a void*, but the smart pointer to the ```TBlob``` object.

Comment: Well, `getData` has to have a return type, and if the return type is TBlob<int> then it can't also be TBlob<float>. Unless you make `getData` a template. You could also make it return void* and let the caller do the cast.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, but the caller (usually the user) must know which type to cast. That is a bit bothering, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) directly, after C++17.

if you can't use that or just want to define another one, refer to [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

Comment: That's what I want! Thank you!

Comment: Note that you still need to know which type is in the variant, in order to use it...

Comment: @user253751 obviously `std::variant<std::vector<float>, std::vector<double>, ...>`, isn't it?

Comment: @RedFog I mean when you want to access the vector inside the variant you need to know what type it is, or use a template to generate all of the cases.

Comment: @user253751 you can (by `std::get`), but you needn't (by `std::visit`).